# Pandas rename selected columns with sequential numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with a number or columns, I would like to rename these with incremental numbers selecting the starting and ending range.

[image]

With the above image, I would like to select only columns B-D, and rename them to 1-4. So the resulting data frame would be:

[image]

So basically selecting the headers via index numbers and adding incremental numbers instead.

EDIT: The above dataframe

```
data = [['a','b','c','d','e','f'], ['a','b','c','d','e','f'], ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],['a','b','c','d','e','f']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
```

Comment: Adding an example dataframe to work on instead of the images might give people the extra incentive to start on your question

Comment: @PatrykKowalski Thank You - I have made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rename` with selected columns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - here between `B` and `E`:

```
c = df.loc[:, 'B':'E'].columns
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(c, range(1, len(c) + 1))))
print (df)
   A  1  2  3  4  F
0  a  b  c  d  e  f
1  a  b  c  d  e  f
2  a  b  c  d  e  f
3  a  b  c  d  e  f
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is something you have to do frequently, you can write a custom function for that:

```
def col_rename(df, start, stop, inplace=False):
    cols = list(df.loc[:, start:stop].columns)
    new_cols = df.columns.map(lambda x: {k:v for v,k in
                                         enumerate(cols, start=1)
                                        }.get(x, x))
    if inplace:
        df.columns = new_cols
    else:
        return new_cols

df.columns = col_rename(df, 'B', 'F')

# or
# col_rename(df, 'B', 'F', inplace=True)
```

output:

```
   A  1  2  3  4  F
0  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(6)], columns=list('ABCDEF'))

#    A  B  C  D  E  F
# 0  0  1  2  3  4  5
```